# The "recovery" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Just now, I saw [recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery). I'm not sure what to do about it, but it seems it needs to go, because it isn't specific enough. File recovery? Recovering a system to a usable state? The tag has a variety of questions in it. Perhaps it should be blacklisted and it be recommended that more specific tags like [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) be used instead. It reminds me of the old [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) mess.

Comment: I've seen it couple of times, it never made sense to me, as "*recovering* what?", btw, related of [other meta](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8290/235569) in which you can find reasons to burn it.

Answer (score 2):

So, yeah, just clean it up. Remove the tag and replace where applicable with either [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) or [password-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/password-recovery). There are some where none of the three tags apply, so watch-out.

To make life easier, check out these:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery+data-recovery [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) + [recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery+password [password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/password) + [recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery)