# Give [recovery] the [installation] treatment

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-block-request

Let's talk for a minute about the [recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery) tag, [again](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11872/the-recovery-tag).

There are many different kinds of recovery, including (but not limited to):

- [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery), for recovering lost data,
- [password-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/password-recovery), for recovering a lost password,
- [recovery-mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery-mode), for doing recovery things,
- System Recovery, for recovering systems from Big Mistakes™.

Right now, [recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery) is automatically replaced with [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery), which is a misuse of synonyms in my own opinion. We don't have [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) redirecting to [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation), so [recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery) tag shouldn't be synonymized to [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery).

Therefore, I propose we remove the synonymization of [recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery) and request a blacklist of the tag. Furthermore, we add a warning in the usage guidelines, similar to the following:

> **DO NOT USE THIS TAG!** Instead, use one of the appropriate recovery tags: [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) for lost data, [recovery-mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery-mode) for the eponymous boot mode, or [password-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/password-recovery) for a lost password.
>
> Tag used for questions about any form of recovery operations on Linux.

Comment: great idea. +1 from me

Comment: Seems sensible. Not sure we need a tag dedicated to password recovery though.

Comment: agree with Seth, we have a [password] tag so no need for [password-recovery] imho. But otherwise I agree with the idea

Comment: +1, but I think we also need a `system-recovery` tag